# Unable to change tkinter Canvas background color on mouse hover?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to change background color of complete canvas whenever a mouse hovers over it. Have this code for it. Minimal Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class HoverCanvas(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, activebackground, **kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master=master,**kw)
        self.defaultBackground = self["background"]
        self.activebackground = activebackground
        self.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

    def on_enter(self, e):
        self.config(background=self.activebackground)

    def on_leave(self, e):
        self.config(background=self.defaultBackground)



root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1280x720")

canvas = HoverCanvas(root, 'red', bg='#212121', width=1280, height=720)
#canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg='#212121', width=1280, height=720)
canvas.create_text(110, 15, fill="#304ffe", activefill='#6a1b9a', font="Times   14 bold", text="Soccer Data Scraper v1.0")
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Color of canvas changes to red when mouse is pointed over it, if it's empty (see commented line).
However if I try to add a text, or any other widget on canvas, the program stops working and throws a cryptic error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "canvasbg.py", line 24, in <module>
canvas.create_text(110, 15, fill="#304ffe", activefill='#6a1b9a', font="Times  14 bold", text="Soccer Data Scraper v1.0")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2501, in create_text
return self._create('text', args, kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2477, in _create
*(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: bad option "create": must be cget or configure
```

What is this error? Is there any way to change background color of canvas on cursor hover while also having other widgets/text in it ?

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class inherits from `tk.Canvas`

```
class HoverCanvas(tk.Canvas):
```

but you call the `__init__` method of `tk.Frame`

```
tk.Frame.__init__(self,master=master,**kw)
```

You should call the `__init__` method of `tk.Canvas` instead.

Comment: Hello, thank you! I feel so stupid. Thanks for pointing it out.